# Isotope and Instagram Jquery plugins - Updating a text input val( ) dynamically inside a jQuery click function

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-isotope, instagram

I am working on some code that uses the [Instagram](https://github.com/potomak/jquery-instagram) query plugin to load photos into a page and Jquery [Isotope](https://github.com/desandro/isotope) to do the layout. I have it working except that I want the ability to enter a hash name in a text input that will load those images tagged with that hash name. I have a button that loads the images. It works great the first time I enter the text input but I can't get the hash to update in the button click function when the text input changes. I'm wondering if I need to use delegate for this? Any help would be appreciated
I am a novice jquery coder so I realize my code is in need of some fine tuning.

```
$(function(){

var selectedHash = $( "input:text[name=hash]" ).val();    
var insta_container = $(".instagram"), insta_next_url;

 insta_container.instagram({
    hash: selectedHash,
    clientId : '4cc3fc9df774483cb575b405f3c1cc21',
    show : 10,
    locationId: '',
    onComplete : function (photos, data) {
  var insta_next_url = data.pagination.next_url;
  $(function(){ 
  $('div.instagram').imagesLoaded( function(){
    $(this).isotope({
      itemSelector : '.item',
      masonry: {
     columnWidth: 170
   }
    });
   });
      });      
    }
  });

$('button.add').bind('click', function(){
  var button = $(this); 
  var selectedHash = $( "input:text[name=hash]" ).val();    
   insta_container.instagram({
       next_url : insta_next_url,
       hash: selectedHash,
       clientId : '4cc3fc9df774483cb575b405f3c1cc21',
        show : 10,
        onComplete : function(photos, data) {
      insta_next_url = data.pagination.next_url;

        var $newItems = $(insta_next_url);
    $('div.instagram').prepend($newItems).isotope( 'reloadItems' ).isotope({ sortBy: 'original-order' });
    }
  });  
 });



});
```

Comment: Add some `console.log( /* variable here */ )` lines to the `click` and `onComplete` functions. Is selectedHash changing? Is the Instagram ajax running? Is it returning the expected data?

Comment: So, you're trying to have the text input's val() put in as the button's text after they hit the button?

Comment: Also, in your `button.add` click event you have `button.text(text)`, i don't see `text` defined anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be removed. It was for the button to show "loading" when clicked and I meant to not show extraneous code. I'm trying to get the text inputs val() into hash: selectedHash,

Comment: I suggest you check the content of `selectedHash` using Timothy's example above. I have a feeling the problem isn't with the `selectedHash` not updating, but rather code with isotope.

Comment: selectedHash changes as expected as the text input changes. What I see not changing is the hash name within insta_next_url. The first text entry works for both but subsequent ones only change the  selectedHash.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's one problem.

```
var selectedHash = $( "input:text[name=hash]" ).val();
```

... should be ...

```
var selectedHash = $( "input[name='hash']" ).val();
```

Comment: Whoa. `$( "input:text[name=hash]" )` actually works. Scratch that.
Learned something new today. :)